# Dispose a SqlConnection with connection pooling on?

Tags: ado.net, connection-pooling

If connection pooling is on, then connections are in actual fact, always open. The only difference for a connection is whether the connection is returned to the pool or it is in use. Closing it returns it to the pool, but the connection is still opened. Is this right? If this is true,

-then I think calling Connection.Dispose( ) always is not good when using a connection pool,

since disposing is like destroying the connection, when actually you want to just return the connection to the pool. **The next time you use a connection from a pool, it will be very fast since that connection is still sticking to the resources it needs to for remaining an open connection in the pool.** You don't want a connection from a pool to re-acquire the non-managed resources it needs as that will bring down performance. **So the point is, let the sqlconnection stick to the resources - managed or non-managed as long as its in the pool.** Does this sound right? When we dispose an object, it means we do not want to re-use it, but here we intend to use connections in the pool so why dispose them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your right. When I was researching and article on IDisposable some years ago, I jumped into the framework using reflector, and unlike many other IDisposable objects that had an alternate method like Close() or Free() that just called Dispose() or vice versa, the SqlDbConnection object does different things, one of which was collection pooling.

Unfortuneatly, because the "using" construct is so easy to use, a lot of code examples these days have the DB connection created within a "using" expression, typically as the out most in a set of nested usings.

You could achieve the same thing with a "try" and protected "finally" where you check that the connection is not null and is open before calling close on it. This is the way VB programmers had to do it before they got the "using" keyword.

Another way, though I'm bound to draw some criticism for suggesting it, is to wrap the connection within another thin IDisposable object that takes and exposes an IDbConnection object and calls Close() on the connection within the wrappers Dispose(). It doesn't follow the IDisposable pattern correctly, but if you know why your doing it, understand the impacts, and not hiding it from anyone (either not exporting your code or declare the behaviour) then I can't really see a problem. The last time I used this trick I made it a generic type so that I could tap the concrete DB Connection type without the need to cast it for those functoins that don't accept IDbConnection.